# Add a field to word document using add in using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have created a simple word add in that insert some text to the word document,

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

i want to add my custom fileds to the insert fields from C# model
Example

```
public class test (){
public int id {get;set;}
public int Name{get;set;}
}



 public string ExtractText()
        {
            string filename = RandomString(10);


            #region Create copy of doc 
            var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

           //save document to the same location with different name 
            var path2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                 Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Documents", filename.ToString().Replace(".docx", "") + "V2" + ".docx");
            System.IO.File.Create(path2).Close();
            Document document = app.Documents.Open(path2);
            #endregion

String read = string.Empty;
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < document.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                string temp = document.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();

                if (temp != string.Empty)
                    data.Add(temp);
            }
            #region Add Paragraphs on backend 
            // ********************************************************************************
            //----Add Paragraphs on backend  ----- 
            //********************************************************************************
            data.Add("Next LINE");
            data.Add("Next LINE1");
            data.Add("Second method opens the existing Microsoft Office Word document specified by a fully qualified path and file name. This method returns a Document that represents the opened document");
            data.Add("Contrary <Department> to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney C");
            #endregion
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            //Enable modification
            app.ActiveDocument.Content.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);

            //List<int> paragraphsPermission = new List< int>();
            // List<Tuple<int, string>> paragraphsPermission = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

            List<int> paragraphsPermission = new List<int>();
            //Add text to doc
            foreach (var item in data)
            {

                var para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);

                document.MailMerge.Fields.Add(para.Range ,"Name");


                para.Range.Text = item.Trim();
                para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
                #region Remove this after implementation  
                if (item.Contains("Second"))
                {
                    paragraphsPermission.Add(1);
                }
                else if (item.Contains("Next LINE1"))
                {
                    paragraphsPermission.Add(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    paragraphsPermission.Add(0);
                }
                #endregion
            }
            #region Apply enforceStyle
            app.Visible = true;
            object noReset = true;
            object password = System.String.Empty;
            object useIRM = false;
            object enforceStyleLock = true;
            object PasswordEncryptionFileProperties = false;
            app.ActiveDocument.EnforceStyle = true;
            document.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, ref noReset, "000", ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);
            int nextparagraphs = 1;
            foreach (var item in paragraphsPermission)
            {
                if (item == 1)
                    document.Paragraphs[nextparagraphs].Range.Editors.Add(WdEditorType.wdEditorEditors);
                else
                    document.Paragraphs[nextparagraphs].Range.Editors.Add(WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);
                nextparagraphs++;
            }

            document.Save();
            document.Close();
```

so when user click on the insert filed in Mail merger tab it should show him 
Id and Name

Currently it is disabling the mailings tab i want to enable it from C#
[image]

so the id and name should show on insert merge field

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do... But the Mail Merge feature requires a valid *data source* (database table or query) to be linked to the document. I don't know why the entire Mailings tab would be disabled - that is not standard Word installation default. But it is not possible to use this feature with fields defined in a C# project - that's not what it's for. You need to create a custom UI interface for displaying this information as static text.

Comment: @CindyMeister 
I the above code I created a document and adding restrict editing on some paragraph and its working fine. Now I want to bind the data source of mail merge with the “test” class so I can see these fields when user click on insert fields.and also can able to insert the field in the doc

Comment: There is nothing in Word that will allow binding mail merge with a class in C#. Mail Merge can only work with a file as data source. If the class member fields were exported to a csv file, for example, mail merge could be linked to that. But the editing restriction is likely locking out mail merge... What you'll need to do is create your own interface for the user to insert the content. If this were VSTO then that could be done via the Ribbon or a Custom Task Pane. If this is a WinForm or other kind of solution then you'll need a form hosted in the solution.